# Java: how to render system font in bold on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, swing, fonts

I have a simple java app:

```java
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Math fonts rendering examples");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);

        Container c = frame.getContentPane();

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Cambria Math: [a, b]");
        label1.setBounds(50, 50, 400, 30);
        label1.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Cambria Math: [a, b]");
        label2.setBounds(50, 100, 400, 30);
        label2.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.BOLD, 30));

        c.add(label1);
        c.add(label2);
```

I run it on Windows, MacOS and Ubuntu.
The font 'Cambria Math' installed into the system and available for JVM (i.e. this font is system, no need additional actions to register it in Java).

Windows (ok):
[image]

MacOs (not ok):
[image]

Ubuntu (ok):
[image]

As you can see, there isn't difference between Cambria Math normal and bold on MacOS.

On MacOS I've tried to move the font from the system folder (`/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Cambria Math.ttf`) to the user's folder `~/myfonts/Cambria Math.ttf`, and then register this font in Java like this:

```java
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font ttfFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(fontFile));
ge.registerFont(ttfFont);
```

After that the normal and bold fonts look differently (as expected)
[image]

I've found a bug opened 6(six!) years ago:
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8176835
but can't believe that there isn't any workaround solution.

My questions:

- is there any workaround solution for this issue on Mac?
- is there a way to re-register font in Java from the another folder?

Comment: Is there a separate font called Cambria Math Bold?  IIRC (from a long time ago) some fonts actually have a completely separate packaging for bold and italic.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/bold-italic-math-with-unicode-math

Comment: @JimGarrison No, only Cambria Math normal.

Comment: @BillMair I didn't understand how TeX issue relates to my one.

Comment: @AlexanderDyuzhev Ref Bold --> "even Cambria Math (the de-facto standard OT math font) does not have one" -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/bold-italic-math-with-unicode-math#comment115951_55410